# Django user details

Tags: python, django

I  am doing a project in Django. In route `/players` I have list of all players in my database. On each player's card, I would like to have a link, which redirects me to a player profile, like `/players/username`. I tried it with some URL parameter but after some attempts I need some help. I know how to do it in Node, but in django it seems a bit complicated for me.

I got this error
`Reverse for 'player-profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['players/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']`

This is my link on each player card in players.html

`<a href="{% url 'player-profile' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Profil</a>`

This is URL pattern in urls.py

`path('players/<username>/', views.player_profile, name='player-profile')`

This is player_profile function in views.py

````
def player_profile(request, username):
    return render(request, 'blog/player_profile.html```
````

Comment: The link should include the username, so `<a href="{% url 'player-profile' my_username %}" class="btn btn-primary">Profil</a>` with `my_username` an expression to derive the suername.

Comment: Thanks! It worked